# xaml opening a popup for the second time errors

Tags: c#, wpf

I am displaying search results in a DataGrid on a popup window, once an item is selected the popup is closed and the selected item is displayed on the page.  It all works fine for the first open and close but when I try to re-open the popup I get an unhandled exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll" on the             OnPropertyChanged("IsOpen") call

View:

```
<Button x:Name="btSearch" Command="{Binding SearchNoteCommand}">
    <Image Source="images/search.jpg"/>
</Button>
<GroupBox x:Name="grpSearchPopup" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Width="170" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
    <Popup Name="popSearch" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}" Margin="122,89,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="dgSearchResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentNote.SearchResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFED676E" AlternationCount="2" Background="{x:Null}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NoteID}" Width="25" Header="ID"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Note}" Width="100" Header="Note"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}" Width="70" Header="Date"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Width="60" Header="Time"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</GroupBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
private bool _isOpen;
public bool IsOpen
{
    get { return _isOpen; }
    set
    {
        if (_isOpen == value) return;
        _isOpen = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsOpen");
    }
}
private NoteModel.SearchResult _selectedItem;
public NoteModel.SearchResult SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedItem)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            if (_selectedItem != null)
            {
                noteData.FetchNote(CurrentNote, _selectedItem.NoteID);
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentNote");
                //close the popup for search results
                IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
private ICommand _searchNote;
public ICommand SearchNoteCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_searchNote == null)
        {
            _searchNote = new RelayCommand(
                p => this.CanSearchNote(),
                p => this.SearchNote());
        }
        return _searchNote;
    }
}
private bool CanSearchNote()
{
    if (Search != null)
        return true;
    return false;
}
private void SearchNote()
{
    noteData.SearchNotes(CurrentNote, Search);
    //open the popup for search
    IsOpen = true;
}
```

Error happens here:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
         var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);   
         this.PropertyChanged(this, e);   <----- error
    }
}
```

NoteData.cs

```
public bool SearchNotes(NoteModel CurrentNote, string sSearch)
        {
            //check the open connection
            if (ConnectData.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string SQLSearch = "select note_id, date, time, note from note where date like '%" + sSearch + "%' or time like '%" + sSearch + "%' or note like '%" + sSearch + "%' group by note_id, date, time, note";

                    //get the phone types for lookups
                    SqlCommand cmdSearchNotes = new SqlCommand(SQLSearch, ConnectData.connection);
                    SqlDataReader drSearchResults = cmdSearchNotes.ExecuteReader();
                    CurrentNote.SearchResults = new List<NoteModel.SearchResult>();

                    while (drSearchResults.Read())
                    {
                        CurrentNote.SearchResults.Add(new NoteModel.SearchResult()
                        {
                            NoteID = (int)drSearchResults["note_id"],
                            Date = drSearchResults["date"].ToString(),
                            Time = drSearchResults["time"].ToString(),
                            Note = (string)drSearchResults["note"]
                        });
                    }
                    drSearchResults.Dispose();
                    cmdSearchNotes.Dispose();

                    //close Connection
                    ConnectData.CloseConnection();

                    return true;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    return false;
                    throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong with fetching the note search results: ", ex);
                }
            }
            //connection failed
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

public bool FetchNote(NoteModel CurrentNote, int NoteID)
{
    //check the open connection
    if (ConnectData.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            string SQLSearch = "select note_id, date, time, note from note where note_id = " + NoteID;

            //get the phone types for lookups
            SqlCommand cmdFetchNote = new SqlCommand(SQLSearch, ConnectData.connection);
            SqlDataReader drFetchNote = cmdFetchNote.ExecuteReader();

            while (drFetchNote.Read())
            {
                CurrentNote.NoteID = (int)drFetchNote["note_id"];
                CurrentNote.Date = drFetchNote["date"].ToString();
                CurrentNote.Time = drFetchNote["time"].ToString();
                CurrentNote.Note = (string)drFetchNote["note"];
                CurrentNote.SearchResults = null;
            }
            drFetchNote.Dispose();
            cmdFetchNote.Dispose();

            //close Connection
            ConnectData.CloseConnection();

            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong with fetching the note: ", ex);
        }
    }
    //connection failed
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   σε System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Verify()
   σε System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   σε System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   σε System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.SetRootVisualToPopupRoot()
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean asyncCall)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   σε System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   σε System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   σε System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   σε System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   σε System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   σε MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean dependencySourcesChanged, Boolean initialValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   σε MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   σε MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(Object o, String propName)
   σε MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
   σε System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   σε ObservableObject.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) στο C:\Users\treej\Source\Repos\FiloFix\FiloFix\Helper Classes\ObservableObject.cs:γραμμή 24
   σε FiloFix.ViewModel.NoteViewModel.set_IsOpen(Boolean value) στο C:\Users\treej\Source\Repos\FiloFix\FiloFix\ViewModel\NoteViewModel.cs:γραμμή 113
   σε FiloFix.ViewModel.NoteViewModel.SearchNote() στο C:\Users\treej\Source\Repos\FiloFix\FiloFix\ViewModel\NoteViewModel.cs:γραμμή 50
   σε FiloFix.ViewModel.NoteViewModel.<get_SearchNoteCommand>b__8_1(Object p) στο C:\Users\treej\Source\Repos\FiloFix\FiloFix\ViewModel\NoteViewModel.cs:γραμμή 35
   σε RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) στο C:\Users\treej\Source\Repos\FiloFix\FiloFix\Helper Classes\RelayCommand.cs:γραμμή 28
   σε MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   σε System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   σε System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   σε System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   σε System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   σε System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   σε System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   σε System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   σε System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   σε System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   σε System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   σε System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   σε System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   σε System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   σε MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   σε MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   σε System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   σε System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   σε System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   σε MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   σε MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   σε System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   σε System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   σε System.Windows.Application.RunDispa...
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you triggering the SearchNoteCommand. Sounds like something is being dispatched on the wrong thread.

Comment: It is being triggered from the view search button.

Comment: When the exception stops your program which thread is it in? Have a look in the __threads__ window.  Also make sure all exceptions are turned (Debugs/Windows/Exception Settings) on so you catch the first one thrown.

Comment: How is _SearchResults_ generated. Any chance that this property is modified from a different thread as the result of a database query or HTTP call or something?

Comment: I'm guessing that this line of code is the bad boy _noteData.SearchNotes(CurrentNote, Search);_ How does it do the search?

Comment: Sorry, I have amended the detail in the question,  the error is happening in the OnPropertyChanged (as above).  The thread is the Main thread.  The SearchResults is the Data class.

Comment: As a side issue you should be taking advantage of the __using__ keyword rather than explicitly disposing objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. Notice that if you get an SQLException you don't end up calling Dispose on any of your objects. __using__ solves that problem for you.

Comment: thanks, i did not think of that.

Comment: Please include the whole stack trace including all the way down to PresentationFramework.

Comment: And what was the value of the __propertyName__ variable when the exception occurred.

Comment: The property name is "IsOpen"

Comment: The message in the exception is: 
An element ItemsControl is inconsistent with the origin of the data.
  See inside exception message for more information.

Comment: Ok. Now we are getting somewhere. That particular error has a huge [google footprint](https://www.google.at/search?q=An+element+ItemsControl+is+inconsistent+with+the+origin+of+the+data&oq=An+element+ItemsControl+is+inconsistent+with+the+origin+of+the+data&aqs=chrome..69i57.503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  Read some of the articles. However I'm puzzled because it doesn't look like you are updating the ItemsSource bound collection from another thread. Are you sure you are not missing some vital information?

Comment: I think it is because I am changing the CurrentNote.SearchResults on the second click but I am not sure how that would affect the IsOpen propery, the popup is not bound itself, other than too the IsOpen property but the datagrid in the popup is bound to the CurrentNote.SearchResults

Comment: See my answer. I think I see the problem. You should not change the list after you assign to CurrentNote.SearchResults as that property has been bound to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
public bool SearchNotes(NoteModel CurrentNote, string sSearch)
    {
        //check the open connection
        if (ConnectData.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                string SQLSearch = "select note_id, date, time, note from note where date like '%" + sSearch + "%' or time like '%" + sSearch + "%' or note like '%" + sSearch + "%' group by note_id, date, time, note";

                //get the phone types for lookups
                SqlCommand cmdSearchNotes = new SqlCommand(SQLSearch, ConnectData.connection);
                SqlDataReader drSearchResults = cmdSearchNotes.ExecuteReader();

                // CHANGE IS HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                var list = new List<NoteModel.SearchResult>();

                while (drSearchResults.Read())
                {
                    CurrentNote.SearchResults.Add(new NoteModel.SearchResult()
                    {
                        NoteID = (int)drSearchResults["note_id"],
                        Date = drSearchResults["date"].ToString(),
                        Time = drSearchResults["time"].ToString(),
                        Note = (string)drSearchResults["note"]
                    });
                }

                // CHANGE IS HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
                CurrentNote.SearchResults = list;
                drSearchResults.Dispose();
                cmdSearchNotes.Dispose();

                //close Connection
                ConnectData.CloseConnection();

                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
                throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong with fetching the note search results: ", ex);
            }
        }
        //connection failed
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Note I only assign the **CurrentNote.SearchResults** after the list is full. The first time the popup is opened it binds to the list. The next time you click the popup is already bound and when you call

```
CurrentNote.SearchResults = ...
```

Some actions occur within WPF. Then you go and change the contents of that list and this is what causes the error.

Comment: You absolute star :)

Comment: //changed this too
                        list.Add(new NoteModel.SearchResult()
                        {
                            NoteID = (int)drSearchResults["note_id"],
                            Date = drSearchResults["date"].ToString(),
                            Time = drSearchResults["time"].ToString(),
                            Note = (string)drSearchResults["note"]
                        });
                    }

Comment: You are welcome :) It was a nice puzzle to solve. But a hint. Take the message from the exception and stick it in google. That was the missing information that clued me in on what to look for.